# wso2 ESB Aggregator - AggregateMediator Error evaluating expression

Tags: java, wso2, esb, aggregator, wso2-esb

i have some problem.
i am newbie on ESB, i just try WSO2 ESB.
i want try example about wso2 ESB Aggregator, to aggregate two web services.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/IntegrationPatterns/Aggregator

i have do all the steps. But i get some errors.

=================

```
[2013-09-06 13:19:14,987] ERROR - AggregateMediator Error evaluating expression:
 //m0:getQuoteResponse
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Could not find matching elements to aggrega
te.
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.EIPUtils.enrichEnvelope(EIPUtils.jav
a:148)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.getAggr
egatedMessage(AggregateMediator.java:398)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.complet
eAggregate(AggregateMediator.java:345)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.mediate
(AggregateMediator.java:290)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
diator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(A
xis2SynapseEnvironment.java:239).....
```

============

anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works fine. In your error log the error is about `//m0:getQuoteResponse` tag in soap body. I think this is due to namespace error in your configuration.
The corresponding namespace should be `http://services.samples`

Comment: where i should set namespace configuration http ://service.samples ?.  can you give me the example.

Comment: <onComplete xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" expression="//m0:getQuoteResponse">

Answer (score 0):

Check the axis2server log.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /services/SimpleStockQuoteService/
```

If this is the error.

You need to build the sample project SimpleStockQuoteService using ant. then it will deploy the sample project into the axis2server.